# Amplify Init Error - ✖ Root stack creation failed init failed TypeError: Cannot redefine property: default

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

Using amplify init, right after choosing which profile to use, I get this error and am not sure why: 
✖ Root stack creation failed
init failed
TypeError: Cannot redefine property: default

- I tried changing the different user to be my default in my credentials file and then picking the default profile in the amplify init step for that - same error.
- I tried saying I didn't want to use a profile and instead putting in my access key id and secret key in manually, also didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found solution here! [github issues](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/1966)

Relevant quote - "I found the source of my problem... My ~/.aws/config file contained entries called [default] and [profile default], which causes the symptom."

So I removed the [default] and just left my [profile default] and then the amplify init went through normally!

Comment: Open the file with any text editor of your choosing and then you should be able to edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Amplify expects you to have had an existing user with **AdministrationFullAccess**. This should be confirmed before running **amplify init** or perhaps when you run the **amplify init** you will be prompted if you would be using the default AWS Profile or not. In this case, you might have to create the user yourself and attach a policy to the user and paste both the access and secret keys to the respective section on the console. But when you follow the steps to create a user with amplify configure it is so easy.